# Android Q : background activity starts

Tags: android, android-activity, android-10.0

https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/background-activity-starts

Workng on Android Q , launching activity from background.

**Apps running on Android Q can start activities only when one or more of the following conditions are met:**

**"The app has an activity in the back stack of the foreground task."**

Can someone explain what is "foreground task" mean here with example.

Thanks

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack for an explanation of tasks and their back stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "foreground task" is the task that contains the `Activity` that is currently on visible on screen (ie: the viewable `Activity`).

The "foreground task" can also contain other activities, that either belong to the same app, or to different apps. All of these activities, since they are "covered" by the viewable `Activity`, are **"in the back stack of the foreground task"**.

Here's a (hypothetical) example:

You launch a photo viewer app, choose a photo, edit the photo using a meme maker, then choose "send via Email" and are now in the Email app composing an Email. The back stack of the "foreground task" looks like this:

```
PhotoViewerMainActivity->PhotoViewerPhotoActivity->MemeMakerActivity->EmailComposerActivity
```

The current, top-most, viewable `Activity` is EmailComposerActivity, which is the one that you can see on screen. The other activities are covered by the viewable `Activity`.

Any code that belongs to the `PhotoViewer` App, the `MemeMaker` App or the `EmailComposer` app is allowed to start an `Activity`, based on the rules for Android Q.

If you now press the HOME button, the "foreground task" will be moved to the background and activities in it will no longer be "in the back stack of the foreground task"

Comment: Thanks for the clear cut use case! My uderstanding was right! Wish google document was more friendly like this :)

Answer (score 0):

> The app has an activity in the back stack of the foreground task

This means that your application has an Activity in the backstack of the foreground task, literally. So when looking at your current activity, if you press "back" and pop the backstack, an Activity is there (instead of this being your top-most activity in the stack and therefore "exiting" your app when you press back)

To better understand the phrase, you'd need to be familiar with [Android Task Stack management](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack) ;)

Good luck.

Comment: task=Stack of activities..i have cordova app with only 1 activity, can it ever have foreground task? Can you elobrate more with example on foreground task from where activity can be launched?

Comment: A task is one or more activities in a pile. Think of piles of things. You put one on top of another. But you can have more than one task (Pile) of activities. That means you can go back to the previous in the task (pile) or you can elect to go to another pile. You really need to read the above link. it's all explained in much better detail in the official Android documentation. David's answer also provides an example. If you only have 1 activity, and it's visible, then it's the foreground task.